# Understanding Local Function Capturing of Variables inside Loops

Tags: c#, loops, scope, delegates, local-functions

I've noticed the following. This C# code:

```
        List<Action> methodList = new List<Action>();
        for (int iFn = 0; iFn < 4; ++iFn)
        {
            void thisLocalFunction()
            {
                string output = iFn.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
            methodList.Add(thisLocalFunction);
        }
        
        for (int iFn = 0; iFn < methodList.Count; ++iFn)
        {
            methodList[iFn]();
        }
```

Produces 4, 4, 4, 4. On the other hand, this code:

```
        List<Action> methodList = new List<Action>();
        for (int iFn = 0; iFn < 4; ++iFn)
        {
            string output = iFn.ToString();
            void thisLocalFunction()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
            methodList.Add(thisLocalFunction);
        }
        
        for (int iFn = 0; iFn < methodList.Count; ++iFn)
        {
            methodList[iFn]();
        }
```

Produces 0, 1, 2, 3.

I'm not sure I understand why. I've read a bit about "capturing" but I'm not sure if that's related to what's going on here. Could someone give me a breakdown of why the two implementations behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical bit of code that you've moved, `string output = iFn.ToString();` turns `iFn` into a string *when it is run*

In the first example, it is run *after the loop has finished* (but "by magic" a single `iFn` is still available). Of course, after the loop finishes, iFn is 4 (because that's how the loop stopped). Why is it run after the loop finishes? because you "created a method and stored it in a variable" and the call to turn `iFn` into a string is *inside this method*. You didn't *run* the method you created while you were in the loop, so iFn was never turned into a string while you were in the loop. The method-in-a-variable was only run afterwards, and because the method contains the code that turns `iFn` into a string, it accesses `iFn` at whatever current value it has, which is 4.

In the second example iFn is turned into a string *as the loop is executing* so the value is 0, then 1, then 2, then 3. This is stored in a new variable (called `output`) that the method you created in the loop, has access to (again, let's say the method can still access `output`, even though it looks like it's out of scope, "by magic"), but the value of `output` is generated on each pass of the loop and then given to the method. In essence each of your 4 methods-as-a-variable stored in the list has access to a *different* variable called `output` - the first method' output has a value of 0, the second method's variable called `output` has a value of 1..

You could conceive that when you create a method that you will later invoke, the "environment variables" the method had access to at the time it was created, are packaged up with it so that it has its own little environment to execute in. In the first case, each of the 4 methods has access to `iFn` at whatever value it is now, whereas in the second they have access to `output` at whatever value it had when it was in the loop. Just because the variable is named the same on each pass of the loop doesn't mean it's reusing the same memory location to hold the data

Comment: That mostly makes sense! So how is iFn still available, "by magic," if I run the local function somewhere else where I normally wouldn't expect it to still be in scoop?

Comment: No indeed; that's why it's magic. It might help to think of it as "when you create a method and assign it to a varaible, C# get a list together of all the variables that are in scope for it at the time, and gives it access to them. Because the method carries on having access to them they didn't actually go out of scope after all; they become part of a sort of mini execution environment that the method will need to do its work. It's hard, because it *looks* like "they're out of scope" because you're used to the rule "not in the same or parent set of curly braces; not in scope"

Comment: ..but you kinda have to get used to this "invisible" part of scope; you're already OK with it when you can see it - in that you can assign a normal variable in a child scope, to a variable created in a parent and you wouldn't expect the parent to suddenly lose the data as the child scope exits "because the parent reference is still in scope" => just consider that C# decided that your anonymous method needed access to `iFn` so it allowed a reference to it to persist because the anonymous method refers to it and the anon method hasn't gone out of scope yet (but you can't "see" the reference)